# Decoding Dictionary object without associated Key

Tags: json, swift, codable, decoder

i have a model class that has type and data and in the backend i have added one another dictionary that does not have codingKey associated to fetch the data . How can i parse the data in this case.

below is the model class

```
struct OverviewWorkout : Codable {

    enum WorkoutType: String , Codable {
        case workout
        case coach
    }
    
    enum WorkoutsData  {
      case workout(Workout)
      case coach(CoachInstruction)
    }
    
    var type: WorkoutType
    var data : WorkoutsData

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        type =  try container.decode(WorkoutType.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case .workout:
            let data = try container.decode(Workout.self, forKey: .data)
            self.data = .workout(data)
        case .coach:
            let data = try container.decode(CoachInstruction.self, forKey: .data)
            self.data = .coach(data)
        }
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type,data

    }
}


extension OverviewWorkout {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch data {
        case .workout(let workout):
            try container.encode("workout", forKey: .type)
        case .coach(let coach):
            try container.encode("coach", forKey: .type)
        }
      } 
}
```

here is the response from backend

```json
[
     data =     {
        data = custom title;
    };
    type = coach;
},
{
    data =     {
   
        duration = "5 min";
}

{
rankMontly = 4
rankWeekly = 6
rankYearly = 90
}

]}
```

so my question is how can i parse the last object in the response , which is seems to be a dictionary object with key value pairs of weeklyrank , monthlyrank etc.

Comment: It's unclear. On the second one, there is no `type` either, so how do you know how to parse it? I guess you have an associated value to handle ranks?

Comment: nope there is not any associated key with ranks object

Comment: workout and coach data i am able to fetch from backend

Comment: the issue is the third object which does not have any key but the object is itself a dictionary of ranks , so how can i parse this object.

Comment: In your sample, isn't it missing `"type": "workout"`, or since your printed a `NSArray`/`NSDictionary` using OpenStep Format, `type = workout;`?

Comment: just let me know is there any way to decode the data object despite of missing the key of that data

Comment: There is a way, but if in the sample you gave, `type = workout;` is not present, it change the way of parsing. I assumed it was there. If not, decoding needs some extra work.

Answer (score 1):

First you need a structure to handle that new object:

```
struct Rank: Codable {
    let monthly: Int
    let weekly: Int
    let yearly: Int

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case monthly = "rankMontly" //Missing a "h" btw?
        case weekly = "rankWeekly"
        case yearly = "rankYearly"
    }
}
```

Let's add that parsing value:

```
struct OverviewWorkout : Codable {

    enum WorkoutType: String , Codable {
        case workout
        case coach
        case rank
    }
    
    enum WorkoutsData  {
      case workout(Workout)
      case coach(CoachInstruction)
      case rank(Rank)
    }
}
```

Let's decode now:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    type = try container.decodeIfPresent(WorkoutType.self, forKey: .type) ?? .rank
    switch type {
    case .workout:
        let data = try container.decode(Workout.self, forKey: .data)
        self.data = .workout(data)
    case .coach:
        let data = try container.decode(CoachInstruction.self, forKey: .data)
        self.data = .coach(data)
    case .rank:
        let container2 = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let data = try container2.decode(Rank.self)
        self.data = .rank(data)
    }
}
```

I assumed that if there is no type, it's a `.rank`. If that's not the case, you might do a `try container.decode` until it works.
Since there is no "sublevel" as expected, I redid the `decoder.container()`, obtaining this time a single value one, since there is one object at top level, and decoded `Rank` on it.

I redid your Encoding part. If you don't use `JSONEncoder` on your app, it's not needed, you can convert `Codable` to `Decodable`, no need to override it. But if you need it, and need to make it looks like in the same format as input:

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    switch data {
    case .workout(let workout):
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(workout, forKey: .data)
        try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)
    case .coach(let coach):
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(coach, forKey: .data)
        try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)
    case .rank(let rank):
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(rank)
    }
}
```

Sample testing:

Adding `CustomStringConvertible` protocol for easier reading:

```
struct OverviewWorkout: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {
        var retValue = "\(type.rawValue) - "
        switch data {
        case .workout(let workout):
            retValue += "duration: \(workout.duration)"
        case .coach(let instruction):
            retValue += "data: \(instruction.data)"
        case .rank(let rank):
            retValue += "y: \(rank.yearly) - m: \(rank.monthly) - w:\(rank.weekly)"
        }
        return retValue
    }

}
```

Then:

```
let jsonStr = """
[{
        "data": {
            "data": "custom title"
        },
        "type": "coach"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "duration": "5 min"
        },
        "type": "workout"
    }, {
        "rankMontly": 4,
        "rankWeekly": 6,
        "rankYearly": 90
    }
]
"""

do {

    let overviewWorkouts = try JSONDecoder().decode([OverviewWorkout].self, from: Data(jsonStr.utf8))
    print(overviewWorkouts)
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted //Just for debug
    let reversed = try encoder.encode(overviewWorkouts)
    let stringified = String(data: reversed, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(stringified)
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Output:

```
$>[coach - data: custom title, workout - duration: 5 min, rank - y: 90 - m: 4 - w:6]

$>[
  {
    "type" : "coach",
    "data" : {
      "data" : "custom title"
    }
  },
  {
    "type" : "workout",
    "data" : {
      "duration" : "5 min"
    }
  },
  {
    "rankMontly" : 4,
    "rankYearly" : 90,
    "rankWeekly" : 6
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer but still i am getting this error. keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "type", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 10", intValue: 10)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"type\", intValue: nil) (\"type\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: as far as i know type is not associated with this last rank object

Comment: well it worked thank you very much . i did a mistake somewhere.